# Windows 10 IoT reduces the disk size to 64MB.

Tags: windows-iot

Just installed Windows 10 IoT into my 16GB Sandisk micro SD card, using the **IoT Dashboard** as described in this [Get Started](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/GetStarted.htm) article.

[image]

But after the completion of flashing, the disk size is reduced to 64MB!

[image]

So the question: how can we retrieve the lost partition? Or, how can we **correctly** install Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: this is just a boot partition, just put your sdcard in RPi and boot it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called partitioning. That's why you sometimes see two 500GB drives when you plug in a 1TB hard drive. There are no mini 500GB hard drives inside a 1TB drive.

Windows 10 simply partitioned it that way. There's a 64MB partition that's visible to your PC. The rest is not visible to your PC (but is being used by Win10 IoT). *Nothing got lost, and nothing got broken.*

So basically, it's **correctly** installed *if it boots up on the Pi.*

Here's a related question: [SD card is titled “RECOVERY” and only has 1GB after using RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43185/24224)